# Could not find "store" in either context or props of Connect(App)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I don't get why I get the error. I did include all the required libraries in my code. Btw, I use navReducer

This is my getStore code:

```
export default function getStore(navReducer) {
const store= createStore(
    getRootReducer(navReducer),
    undefined,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
return store;
}
```

The problem lies in my index.js where I named the class App

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator
(
Routes, 
{
    navigationOptions: {
        title: ({ state }) => {
            if (state.params) {
                return `${state.params.title}`;
            }
        }
    },
    initialRouteName:'Login',
    headerMode:'none'
    }
    );

    const navReducer = (state, action) => {
    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
    };

     const store = getStore(navReducer);

   class AppWithNavigationState  extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator
            navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.nav,
            })}
        />
        );
        }
        }

AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
return {
  nav:state.nav  
}};

export class App extends Component{
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
    );
    }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Sorry my code is too long but I think it's important to include it.

Comment: Did u try  <Provider store= {store}>  ?

Comment: yes, I did try that. Still get the same error

Comment: Can you provide the code of `appStoreConfig`?

Comment: It's actually just a library. import appStoreConfig from '../appStoreConfig';

Comment: Oops sorry, I copied the wrong code. Anyway, I updated the code but still get the same error

Comment: it should be `<Provider store={store}>` and please add the code of `getStore`

Comment: I updated my code yet still the same error.

Comment: did you check that you arent doing something like `import { store } from './app/config/store';` instead of `import store from './app/config/store';`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `connect` on the `Provider`, try:

```
export default App;
```

instead of

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, get new error - undefined is not an object